# Drawing a line with glow around it

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to draw lines with a glow around them as in the following image:

[image]

What is the way to do it with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Billboarded or perspective?

Comment: what do you mean by Billboarded?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. One popular method is to draw the lines you want to have a glow around them into a texture-backed frame buffer. Then post-process the texture by blurring it and adding the blurred copy to the original copy.